# "Couldn't resolve hostname" while installing package in Octave

Tags: octave

I have tried installing a package in Octave using this command:

```
pkg install signal-1.4.0.taz.gz
```

but I received the following error:

```
error: pkg: failed to read package 'signal-1.4.0.taz.gz': Couldn't resolve host name
error: called from
  pkg at line 429 column 17
```

Does somebody know what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mis-spelled the name of the package's tarball. It is likely `signal-1.4.0.tar.gz` rather than `signal-1.4.0.taz.gz` (Note that one has TAR and the other has TAZ in the extension)

```
pkg install signal-1.4.0.tar.gz
```

Essentially what is happening, is that Octave is unable to find the file `signal-1.4.0.taz.gz` on the file system (due to the mis-spelling) so then it attempts to download the file from the internet. When it tries to resolve `signal-1.4.0.taz.gz` as a URL, DNS name resolution fails giving you the error that you're encountering.

Comment: I swear I spent like 5 minutes comparing your two strings before I could spot the typo xD

Comment: I'm currently getting the same error, but I don't have any misspellings.

Comment: @not2qubit Do you have a file named that locally or is it a different name?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou You weren't the only one

Comment: Added some clarifying text :D @OverLordGoldDragon

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue/error when trying to install the econometrics package on a windows install. In my case, for reasons unknown I was getting the following error:

```matlab
>> pkg install econometrics-1.1.1.tar.gz

error: pkg: failed to read package 'econometrics-1.1.1.tar.gz': Couldn't resolve host name
error: called from
    pkg at line 433 column 17
```

The only way I managed to get it, was by first downloading the package manually into the current working directory of Octave. (See `pwd` output.) Only **then** did the install command work.

```matlab
pkg install econometrics-1.1.1.tar.gz
pkg load econometrics
```

Comment: Do you mean you were trying to install it from octave forge? You need to use the `-forge` option for that, e.g. `pkg install -forge econometrics`. Otherwise octave looks for a local package, like the one you downloaded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tested all possible iterations of the *pkg* command...except that one. Anyway, I ended up re-installing Octave and issued the above. But I did interrupt a `pkg update` before having this problem, because the update process was painfully slow and non-verbose while running all my CPU's ~90%. Perhaps that broke something.

Comment: Note-2: I am still convinced I tried that. This also happened after last update from Windows, which is known to have done something funny to the system permissions, breaking all major anti-virus apps, in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I recently have this problem, you need to place the file in the Octave directory and from there rigth clik on the file to copy to clipboard and then paste from there.
example:
[image: example]

Answer (score -2):

to me work to change the document to disc D, and then install like:
pkg install symbolic-win-py-bundle-2.9.0.tar.gz

Comment: Please provide some more information on what the problem may be and why your suggestion is supposed to work. Some external references will also be useful.