# How to pretty print a matrix in Octave?

Tags: matrix, octave, pretty-print

I want to create a pretty printed table from a matrix (or column vector).
For Matlab there are several available functions that can do this (such as *printmat, array2table*, and `table`), but for Octave I cannot find any.

So instead of:

```matlab
>> a = rand(3,2)*10;
>> round(a)
ans =

    2   10
    1    3
    2    1
```

I would like to see:

```matlab
>> a = rand(3,2)*10;
>> pretty_print(round(a))

   THIS   THAT
R1    2   10
R2    1   3
R3    2   1
```

**How can I produce a pretty printed table from a matrix?**
(Any available package to do so?)

---

**UPDATE**

After trying to follow the extremely obtuse package installation instruction from Octave Wiki, I kept getting the error [`pkg: failed to read package 'econometrics-1.1.1.tar.gz': Couldn't resolve host name`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55855848/1147688). Apparently the windows version isn't able to use the direct installation command (as given on their Wiki). The only way I managed to get it, was by first downloading the package manually into the current working directory of Octave. (See `pwd` output.) Only **then** did the install command work.

```matlab
pkg install econometrics-1.1.1.tar.gz
pkg load econometrics
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a [*prettyprint*](https://octave.sourceforge.io/econometrics/function/prettyprint.html) function in the [`econometrics`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/econometrics/overview.html) package. Once the package is installed and loaded, you can use it like this:

```
>> a = rand(3,2)*10;
>> prettyprint(round(a),['R1';'R2';'R3'],['THIS';'THAT'])

          THIS        THAT
R1       2.000       3.000
R2       3.000       4.000
R3      10.000       3.000
```

Comment: There's also the dataframe package

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Yeah, super crappy documentation as usual! What is the function called in that package?

Comment: @m304 So that's where it went! These are only 2 of a great number of packages that are so poorly documented! Look at the link to the function. It's a blank page. No wonder Octave never *took off* as a useful product, even if free.

Comment: @not2qubit no need for rudeness. I'm not referring to a 'function'. The dataframe package provides the dataframe object. Simple as that. When you display a dataframe it displays its row and column labels. I won't try to defend package documentation per se, but dataframe in particular is extremely well documented. As for the prettyprint function, it _could_ be a bit more documented, and generally I'm the first to rant about proper documentation, but, honestly, in this case, `prettyprint(mat, rlabels, clabels)` is as self-explanatory as it gets ...

Comment: @not2qubit also, I don't have a stake in octave development, but as an independent observer, your assessment of octave not having taken off is wildly off in my experience. And that's even excluding _the_ obvious example of the most popular course on coursera relying exclusively on octave (admittedly, a good percentage of the questions ending up at SO for octave).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Well like you, I am also moving from Matlab to Octave, but the fact remains that clicking the *prettyprint* link in this answer, you get a blank page saying: `this prints matrices with row and column labels`. **That** is certainly not considered proper documentation. Regarding the package name you provided, there is nothing related to *pretty print* in there, so how is anyone supposed to guess how that is done? Almost every single function in the package [datatframe](https://octave.sourceforge.io/dataframe/overview.html) says: `Not documented`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192386/discussion-between-tasos-papastylianou-and-not2qubit).